# Endpoint Routing in ASP.NET Core 2.2 is Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-2.2

**Update (2)**

@poke seems to have figured it out and it looks to be an issue with endpoint routing itself favoring the `{*url}` if there's perceived ambiguity with other higher routes.

**Update (1)**

@poke commented that I had a typo on the `{*url}` route where the *t* in *controller* was missing. After fixing that the `{*url}` route started working and the `DefaultController.Gone` action was working.

**BUT!** Now weird behavior is starting to crop up again. After the `{*url}` was fixed, navigating to `/settings` which is supposed to match the `{controller}/{action}` route fails and falls back to the `{*url}` route.

If I remove the `{*url}` route from the registrations then `/settings` works again. The `{action}` route continues to not work.

**Original**

Please forgive the length of the question, but I am trying to offer as much information as possible.

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 blogging app for myself, and I'm having inexplicable problems getting routing to work. After spending half the day yelling at my screens, I decided to take a step back and start a new project that was completely isolated. Somehow the problems persisted in the new project. I've stripped it down pretty much to a starved skeleton and I still can't get the routes to work. The routes I’m trying to set up are:

```
settings/{controller}/{id:int}/{action} - works
settings/{controller}/{action} - works
blog/{*slug} - works
blog/{skip:int?} - works
{controller}/{action} - works
{action} - doesn't work
{*url} - doesn't work
```

Specifically, I’m having problems with the last two routes.

The `{action}` route is not generating for simple actions like `DefaultController.About` even though it has no constraints, all it has is defaults for `PostsController.List` because I want a list of posts to be shown for the root URL.

The `{*url}` just doesn't seem to work at all. I want to use it as my final fallback and it's defaulted to `DefaultController.Gone`, but if I just bash on the keyboard for some nonsense URL all I get is a 404 error.

I feel that the issue is with the `DefaultController` since both the `About` and `Gone` actions are in it and neither one seems to be working, but I just can't seem to figure out how. It literally does nothing but renders views, just like the other controllers.

Below is the code of the stripped down project. I'd really appreciate it if someone can spin it up and tell me where I'm failing because I certainly can't seem to figure it.

**Program.cs**

```
public sealed class Program {
    public static async Task Main(
        string[] args) => await WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                                       .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                       .Build()
                                       .RunAsync();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(
        IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
    }

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app) {
        app.UseMvc(
            r => {
                //  /settings/{controller}/{id}/{action}
                r.MapRoute("600", "settings/{controller}/{id:int}/{action}", null, new {
                    controller = "Categories|Tags"
                });

                //  /settings/{controller}/{action}
                r.MapRoute("500", "settings/{controller}/{action}", null, new {
                    controller = "Categories|Tags"
                });

                //  /blog/*
                r.MapRoute("400", "blog/{*slug}", new {
                    action = "Show",
                    controller = "Posts"
                });

                //  /blog/{skip}
                r.MapRoute("300", "blog/{skip:int?}", new {
                    action = "List",
                    controller = "Posts"
                });

                //  /{controller}/{action}
                r.MapRoute("200", "{controller}/{action=Default}", null, new {
                    controller = "Settings|Tools"
                });

                //  /{action}
                r.MapRoute("100", "{action}", new {
                    action = "List",
                    controller = "Posts"
                });

                //  /*
                r.MapRoute("-1", "{*url}", new {
                    action = "Gone",
                    conroller = "Default"
                });
            });
    }
}
```

**CategoriesController.cs**

```
public sealed class CategoriesController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Add() => Content("Category added");

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Remove(
        int id) => Content($"Category {id} removed");
}
```

**DefaultController.cs**

```
public sealed class DefaultController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult About() => View();

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Gone() => View();
}
```

**About.cshtml (Default)**

```
<h1>DEFAULT.ABOUT</h1>
```

**Gone.cshtml (Default)**

```
<h1>DEFAULT.GONE</h1>
```

**PostsController.cs**

```
public sealed class PostsController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult List(
        int? skip) => View();

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Show(
        string slug) => View();
}
```

**List.cshtml (Posts)**

```
<h1>POSTS.LIST</h1>
<a asp-action="Show" asp-controller="Posts" asp-route-slug="test-test-test">Show a Post</a>
```

**Show.cshtml (Posts)**

```
<h1>POSTS.SHOW</h1>
```

**SettingsController.cs**

```
public sealed class SettingsController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Default() => View();
}
```

**Default.cshtml (Settings)**

```
<h1>SETTINGS.DEFAULT</h1>
<a asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Categories">Add a Category</a>
<br />
<a asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="Categories" asp-route-id="1">Remove a Category</a>
<hr />
<a asp-action="Add" asp-controller="Tags">Add a Tag</a>
<br />
<a asp-action="Remove" asp-controller="Tags" asp-route-id="1">Remove a Tag</a>
```

**TagsController.cs**

```
public sealed class TagsController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Add() => Content("Tag added");

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Remove(
        int id) => Content($"Tag {id} removed");
}
```

**ToolsController.cs**

```
public sealed class ToolsController :
    Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Default() => View();
}
```

**Default.cshtml**

```
<h1>TOOLS.DEFAULT</h1>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a asp-action="List" asp-controller="Posts">Blog</a>
    <br />
    <a asp-action="Default" asp-controller="Tools">Tools</a>
    <br />
    <a asp-action="About" asp-controller="Default">About</a>
    <br />
    <a asp-action="Default" asp-controller="Settings">Settings</a>
    <br />
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `conroller = "Default"` – There’s a typo, the `t` is missing. Does that fix it? 

Comment: @poke, thanks, it fixed the `{*url}` route, but the `{action}` route is still not generating. Weirdly `/settings` which is supposed to match the `{controller}/{action}` route is now failing and falling back to the `{*url}` route. If I remove the `{*url}` route from the registrations then `/settings` works again. I'm starting to have flashbacks of the bizarre behavior from the original project. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `{action}` - doesn't work

This one doesn’t work because it has to match an actual action. So it works for `/Show` or `/List` since you are operating on the `PostsController`. It also works for `/` since the `action` defaults to `List`.

> `{*url}` - doesn't work

This one *will* work if you set the default `controller`, instead of the `conroller`:

```
r.MapRoute("-1", "{*url}", new
{
    action = "Gone",
    controller = "Default"
});
```

> `<a asp-action="About" asp-controller="Default">About</a>`

Note that this route will also not match because there is no route to that action. The `{controller}/{action}` routes are constrained to the `SettingsController` and `ToolsController`, so the route won’t match. You will need to adjust the constraint or add another route for this to work.

Btw. as a general suggestion: As you probably noticed, managing this many route mapping gets quite complicated. It’s often easier to just use attribute routing with explicit routes. You could also mix those with template based routing to get the best of both worlds.

---

> Weirdly `/settings` which is supposed to match the `{controller}/{action}` route is now failing and falling back to the `{*url}` route. If I remove the `{*url}` route from the registrations then `/settings` works again.

That appears to be a side effect from comining the `settings/{controller}/{action}` and the `{controller}/{action=Default}` routes.

I’ve been debugging through that now for a bit and it seems that this is a bug with endpoint routing, which favors the catch all route although it is being registered later.

Unfortunately, endpoint routing in ASP.NET Core 2.2 is known to break on a few special cases which is why it is being revamped for 3.0 which will hopefully resolve all issues. That being said, I’ve opened [an issue about this particular problem](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9758) and reported my findings. Maybe there’s a simple solution for this.

One easy workaround would be to change the `settings/{controller}/{action}` route template to use a prefix other than `settings`, so that there is no longer an ambiguity. That appears to fix the issues.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see. Since the `{action}` route has a default controller of `Posts` it doesn't matter that I'm specifying the controller in the tag helper because even though I want `Default.About`, the route generated would be `Posts.About` and since the action doesn't exist, the link is blank. Adding the attribute fixes that so I'll concede. That being said, the `{*url}` somehow breaking navigating to `/settings` is still a confusing issue.

Comment: I decided to remove the `{action}` route registration, and I added an attribute for `""` and `"blog"` on the `PostsController.List` action, which covers the root URL and `/blog` URL. I still don't understand why `/settings` routes to the `{*url}` route when the `{controller}/{action}` route is supposed to match first based on the constraints (and order of registration?). It works fine for `/tools`. Removing the `{*url}` route fixes `/settings`. Any guess as to why its behaving this way?

Comment: _“even though I want Default.About, the route generated would be Posts.About”_ – That’s not exactly correct. The way the routing works is that it generates the URLs for all endpoints ahead, so it already knows which route to use for e.g. `PostsController.List`. But it wasn’t able to generate an URL for `Default.About` since no route template matches. So when you try to generate the URL for it, that simply fails.

Comment: As for the `/settings` route, I’ll try to see if I can follow up on that later. For now, one workaround would be to change the `/settings/{controller}/{action}` route to use a different prefix than `settings`. That removes the ambiguity and makes the routes work properly at least.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate, I really appreciate it. Looks like I still have a way to go with endpoint routing... I opted for a different workaround and set the compatibility version to 2.1, and it's routing correctly now. If you're opening an issue, could you link it in here? I'd like to follow it too. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I just created the issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9758 – I’ll update my answer again if there are any results within the next days.